# How to browse a video file from the disk,read and download it at a different loaction onto the disk using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell so as to how to browse for a video file, read its contents and later save it at a user specified location on the disk using javascript

Comment: Can you describe _"later save it at a user specified location on the disk"_?

Comment: I need to browse for a video on the disk,read its contents as a stream or a url and by using this variable having the stream or url i need to save the video to the disk..

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications